# List stored procedures which uses given table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, database

I have around 200 stored procedures and thousands of tables.

I wanted to know which stored procedures are used for accessing (select, insert,..) particular tables, say `user_accounts`.

I am using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Do you need to worry about dynamic SQL?  Might there be some instance where the table name isn't complete (concatenated)?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(S.object_id) StoredProcedure
FROM sys.sql_modules S
JOIN sys.procedures P
ON S.object_id = P.object_id
WHERE Definition LIKE '%user_accounts%' 
OR Definition LIKE '%user_accounts%'
```

It works for me.